# Error configuring Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, configuration, wcf, app-fabric

I have an error while configuring Sharepoint.

How do I unblock WCF data services and AppFabric files and reinstall them?

Comment: what error you are getting and at which step? could you please share more detail about the issue

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any error about WCF data services and AppFabric?

If yes, i suggest you post your special error message

So that we can help you solve it better.

This is a reference about how to: Add, Update, or Remove a WCF Data Service Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668183.aspx

About AppFabric, you can use a variety of methods to uninstall it. You can refer to the following article:
http://www.uninstallhelps.com/how-to-uninstall-windows-server-appfabric-1-1-0-0-rtm.html

About how to install the AppFabric, you can refer to this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637745(v=azure.10).aspx

And this is Windows Server AppFabric download URL:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=15848&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True